# DataTables Enable Select Capability on Specified colums

Tags: datatables

I'm using a [plugin](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/) to create a data table with single row select capability such that when I click anywhere in the row, it links to another page in my web app.  I need help figuring out how to disable the select capability on the first column of every row.  I've tried using css rules but either they do not work or they are applied to columns other than the first.

Table declaration:

```
var locationTable = $('#locationTable').DataTable({
        dom: 'Brtip',
        buttons: [
          'excel'
        ],
        select: {
          style:    'single'
          //selector: ':not(:first-child)'
          //selector: ':not(td:nth-of-type(1))'
        },
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: "/locationData",
        length: 10,
        ordering: false,
        "lengthChange": false,
        //sDom : '<"top">lrtip',
        columns: [              
          {data: 'locationname'},
          {data: 'address1'},
          {data: 'address2'},
          {data: 'city'},
          {data: 'state'},
          {data: 'zipcode'},
          {data: 'phone'},
          {data: 'fax'}
        ]
      });
```

My attempt to configure selection on every column (of every row) except the first:

```
//locationTable.select.selector(':not(tr>td:nth-child(1))');
      locationTable.select.selector('tr>td:nth-child(2)');
```

[demo](http://live.datatables.net/webanera/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Add a CSS rule for each column you wish to enable select capability. In the example below, I wish to have select capability on all columns except the first.

`select: {
          style:    'single',
          selector: 'tr>td:nth-child(2), tr>td:nth-child(3), tr>td:nth-child(4), tr>td:nth-child(5), tr>td:nth-child(6), tr>td:nth-child(7), tr>td:nth-child(8), tr>td:nth-child(9)'
        }`